# Date not getting displayed when used with servlets

Tags: date, servlets

In the below program, the last line in the code is showing an error. df and d cannot be resolved. I used the same logic in a normal Java program and I got the output. Can somebody explain the problem in this.

```
package com.first;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class AgeCalc extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public AgeCalc() {
        super();
        }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //request parameters
        String name1=request.getParameter("name1");
        try {
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
        String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
        Date d=df.parse(dob);

        }
        catch(Exception e){}
        out.println("<html><h3>The name entered is </h3></html>"+name1);
        out.println("<html><body>and the date of birth is </body></html>" +df.format(d));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`d` and `df` variables are defined inside `try` block and are not visible outside of it. Either declare them outside:

```
DateFormat df = null;
Date d = null;
try {
    df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
    d=df.parse(dob);
} catch(Exception e){
}
out.println("<html><h3>The name entered is </h3></html>"+name1);
out.println("<html><body>and the date of birth is </body></html>" +df.format(d));
```

or *better*, wrap everything in one huge `try` block:

```
try {
    DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    String dob=request.getParameter("dob");
    Date d=df.parse(dob);
    out.println("<html><h3>The name entered is </h3></html>"+name1);
    out.println("<html><body>and the date of birth is </body></html>" +df.format(d));
} catch(Exception e){
}
```

This is basic Java, not really related to servlets. Also you **please** do something with the exception, at least:

```
} catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: when wrapped in one try block, response page(after the request is submitted) is shown totally blank.

Comment: @user1295306: please add exception handling, e.g. `e.printStackTrace()`, I believe you are swallowing some exception.

Comment: the reason why i mentioned servlet is, the logic did work with a normal java application, ofcrse with the scope of variables df and d taken care of.. @Tomasz Nurkiewcz

Comment: Date d=df.parse(dob);
I only have the above line of code in try block now, added more to the exception handler .. still getting an error 500..